# magento override price filter slider

Tags: magento-1.9, price

i want to override price filter slider , like add 100 to end price slider , can it be done in some way which event / observer have i to override .

Please guide me way to do this

Comment: Did you check this https://github.com/aurmil/magento-customize-price-filter

Answer (score 1):

Slider is not part of core magento. Ignoring this fact and assuming it is using the same logic as the core:

The price ranges are determined here:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::getPriceRange
```

The maximum price here:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::getMaxPriceInt
```

I think rewriting this model and changing the second method should do the job.

Comment: how can i override getMaxPriceInt value

Comment: Rewrite: http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/